# Why do professors list current position of their students on their webpages?

Tags: academic-life, website

I see that most professors list their former Ph.D students and their 
current positions on their web page. Is it a kind of advertisement? If so, why? If not, why not?

Comment: I am not familiar with that practice, at least if it is exactly as you describe: Is it really *professors* listing the current positions of their alumni on *their* web page, or is it *alumni* who list their current positions on their former *department's* website?

Comment: It's a pure advertisement of how good leader the prof is if his students are so successful.

Comment: @O.R.Mapper Yes, it's exactly as described: some professors, on their own page, have a list of their former PhD students; if a student is still in academia, there'll often be a statement of their current affiliation and/or a link to their homepage.

Comment: What do you mean by “most professors”? Are you referring to professors in a particular jurisdiction? The comments on the answer suggest the rules about this vary significantly between jurisdictions.

Comment: Someone wants to reach person *A*.  He knows that *A* was my student.  So he may look on my web page to see if there is a good link for *A*

Answer (score 47):

In my case at least, I provide this information mostly for the purpose of recruiting future graduate students. By demonstrating that all of my former PhD students and postdocs have landed in desirable positions (be they in academia or in industry), I am able to make a strong case for the value of a PhD obtained as a member of my group.

In my opinion, this is extremely important information for a student when choosing a graduate program and choosing a specific research group. What has happened to previous students? How many have finished? Of those who finished, where are they now? Unfortunately, this information can be quite difficult to obtain unless the professor is willing to provide it. And one needs to know what happened to *all* of the students--knowing that a couple of students are now successful is not that useful unless you know how many others went through the group as well.

Comment: Shouldn't the former students provide consent for this?

Comment: Frankly, I never thought to ask. They all have academic web pages or public LinkedIn pages that provide this information. But I suppose that, particularly for my students now in industry, it might be polite to ask. I can see no legal reason not to, however. Their PhD degrees under my supervision are a matter of (public) academic record, and there is no legal obstacle to saying "John Smith is a chief scientist with StartupCo" so long as it is true.

Comment: "I can see no legal reason not to" - that will depend on the legislation, of course. For instance, while I cannot find any explicit statements now, there are at least [various](http://www.berlin.de/special/jobs-und-ausbildung/arbeitsrecht/2468693-769162-internet-ehemalige-mitarbeiter-muessen-g.html) [clues](http://www.dsb.kit.edu/downloads/DFN_Infobrief_11-2010_Seiten_1-5.pdf) that in Germany, federal privacy laws require employers to remove any profile-like information of their former employees once those employees quit their job. (That notwithstanding, it is common practice in German ...

Comment: ... universities to list alumni; possibly because the alumni are not likely to sue and rather benefit from being listed in that particular case. Still, it remains legally slightly dubious territory.)

Comment: @O.R. I suppose the question then is whether German privacy laws apply to university professors in the same way as former employers; I suspect the language refers specifically to employment relationships though.

Comment: @DanHenderson: For all intents and purposes, the organisational unit within the university that includes the professor's group *is* the employer of the research assistants who are heading for their doctoral degree here.

Comment: Note that in some jurisdictions, students are allowed to mark some or all aspects of their academic profiles/information as confidential and faculty/staff are legally(?) obliged to obey that confidentiality (in fact, if a student marks their entire profile as confidential, faculty/staff can't even say that that information is confidential if someone asks, they have to act like they have no information on the student at all).

Comment: this can also be misleading as a generalization.  I know some labs that only post their successful alumni, for the reasons you state.  But that is not about showing 'all students'

Comment: @O.R.Mapper, PhD is *not* an employee, but a *student*. I believe the law hasn't touched on this matter yet. But I certainly see it coming in litigation-cultures such as the US, unfortunately.

Comment: @Dilworth: Depends on the country. In Germany, at least in CS and some 5 years ago when I was still in academia, people heading for a doctoral degree would usually be *employed* by an institute in a university headed by a professor. That is, they'd sign a work contract with the university and receive a salary. They'd be subject to the wage agreement negotiated by the union that represents university (or rather, public services) employees. They'd get an office, teach in classes, and take no classes or exams.  *Optionally*, they could also register as students, but the only reason to do so ...

Comment: ... would be to get certain benefits such as reduced fares for public transportation. Thus, as I said, this may differ largely by country, but a blanket statement like "PhD is not an employee, but a student." is not quite correct.